# Protractor: If Statement if element contains certain text

Tags: javascript, protractor, aurelia

This seems fairly simple but I can't get this to run. I basically want to check if 'div class = balances' contains the text 'EUR' and if it does, I want to do other checks. It works when I use an expect statement:
`expect(element(by.css('balances')).getText()).toContain('EUR');`
This will pass
But if I change it to:

```js
if (element(by.css('balances')).getText()).toContain('EUR') {
  console.log('true')
}
```

I get an error message: `.toContain is not defined`

What can I use here instead of `.toContain`?
Thanks

Update, I've tried but still no joy:

```html
var bal =element(by.css('balances')).getText().then(function(text){
        if(text.contains('EUR')){
            //do something
        }
       else{
          //do something else
       }
});
```

Comment: You have to use expect. Why would you remove the expect?

Comment: Because I'm not expecting it to contain 'EUR'. I want to check that if it does contain 'EUR'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.getText` returns promise which means you have to resolve it with `.then`.

You want to get the text, resolve the promise, and then do comparison:

```
element(by.css('balances')).getText().then(function(actualText) {
    if(actualText.indexOf('EUR') !== -1) {
        // Yup, I have EUR in me.
    }
});
```

In the `if` statement we use `indexOf` which checks if a string contains specified substring. It returns number of occurrences and if it was not found, it returns `-1`.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: As of node7 you can also switch to using async await which would make the flow a bit easier and not require the then chain